# Angular 7 with Jasmine : Expected element to have text 'x' but instead had text 'x'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write what I thought would be a simple test that checks to confirm that a dynamically rendered card title in my Angular component HTML will have the right title. When I run the test, It fails, Although I can see the bottom mock component renders with the correct title. The message I get in the console is `Expected element to have  text 'Chemical Measurement  <  Environmental Sample ,  Molecule  >', but had 'Chemical Measurement  <  Environmental Sample ,  Molecule  >'`. I've copied and pasted both values from the error and compared them in the browser console and they are the same. Here is the HTML template:

```html
   <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header light-blue">
          <h5>
            <span style="font-weight: bold">
                {{brick?.type.text}}&nbsp;
                &lt;
                <span *ngFor="let dim of brick?.dimensions; let last = last">
                  {{dim.type.text}}
                  <span *ngIf="!last">, </span>
                </span>
                &gt;
            </span>
        </h5>
    </div>
...
```

and here is the spec that I am trying to run (I'm using spectator as a wrapper around angular's default tests):

```js
it('should render meta info', () => {
    const cardTitle = spectator.debugElement.query(By.css('div.card > div.card-header'));
    expect(cardTitle.nativeElement).toHaveText('Chemical Measurement  <  Environmental Sample ,  Molecule  >')
});
```

and the error is:

```
Expected element to have  text 'Chemical Measurement  <  Environmental Sample ,  Molecule  >', but had 'Chemical Measurement  <  Environmental Sample ,  Molecule  >'
```

You can see for yourself if you copy the 2 values in the error and check if they are === to each other, it will return true. What the heck is happening here? Could it be weird behavior from me using elements like `&nbsp;` and `&lt;` in the HTML? I've tried running comparisons for those elements but it interprets it literally in the test.